# wxMaxima: matrix of matrices, vector of vectors, and “.” operator

Tags: matrix-multiplication, maxima

I am studying quarks, SU(3), operators, and all that stuff used in particle physics. I want to automate the boring calculus using [wxMaxima](https://wxmaxima-developers.github.io/wxmaxima/). I have successfully automated everything in the space of only one quark (this is very easy, just matrices and vectors). Now I am working with mesons which are composed of one quark and one antiquark. So the state of a meson is the product of one quark and one antiquark, or a vector of vectors using this representation. And operators in this "meson space" can be considered as matrices of matrices. So I have made the following:

[image]

and I would like wxMaxima to do this:

[image]

I have added labels to the matrices and vectors in the picture to illustrate what I want.

Is this possible without using for cycles? I mean, with the operator '.' or something like that?

EDIT:

In [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/es/) it is very easy to do what I want:

[image]

I think I'll move to sympy.

Comment: The problem is that `.` performs scalar multiplication on the next step instead of carrying through matrix multiplication. One way around is to define your own matrix multiplication `dd(a,b) := sum(a[i,k] . [k, j], ...`. 
@robert-dodier may have a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gather that you want to apply `.` to matrix elements when they're multiplied together. If so, I think `matrix_element_mult : "."` has the effect you want.

See also `matrix_element_add` and `matrix_element_transpose`.